# TLS in Java 11 and Spring Boot 2.2.6

Tags: spring, spring-boot, ssl, tls1.2, java-11

I tried to find anything on the web related but I couldn't we are upgrading our spring-boot services running on java 8 to java 11, Since TLS 1.3 was added in Java 11. This version of TLS is not directly compatible with previous TLS versions do I need to make any changes to keep supporting my current security pattern or spring boot by default will use tls 1.2?

Comment: TLS supports backwards compatibility for both client and server. So upgrading client Server to TLS 1.3 will still support old TLS versions.
Check appendix D for the RFC.
TLS 1.3 RFC: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc8446

Comment: So Java setting TLS version based on the server that is running on, meaning if the server has tls 1.2 enabled this will not effect the clients if I understood this right, please correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: If server has TLS 1.2 enabled it will not effect the clients using TLS 1.1. But there are some constraints on lower versions like SSLv3 which is disabled by Java by default since Java 8, in those cases communication will fail.

Answer (score 0):

TLS v1.3 is not compatible with previous versions, yes.

However, ensuring backwards compatibility for the previous versions is a part of the implementation of TLS v1.3. This was also well-tested during development. The backwards-compatibility configuration is enabled by default.

RFC: http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/332